# Oracle session and process increasing

Tags: oracle, session, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle12c

so I have oracle 12c installed in cantos, the RAM 96GB and the disk are SSD which is pretty fast, and also an application is running on the same server with a lot of conversion and processing of the data.

this was pretty much new system that I installed database and application on it, so after couple of hours I see it give error of

**"got minus one from a read call"**

after digging around I see it was the session and process causing it so in increase that, but still after 24 hours I see the processes and session increasing it does not decrease when checking... bellow is the snap shot of the query during couple of hours I did.

```
select program,username,status,schemaname,count(*) from v$session

group by username,status,osuser,schemaname,program

order by count(*) desc,status

fetch first 3 rows only
```

> 2:00 PM 11 December
>
> JDBC Thin Client                oracleuser INACTIVE             schemeName 233
>
> SQL Developer  SYS         INACTIVE             SYS         4
>
> JDBC Thin Client                oracleuser ACTIVE schemeName 3

```
select * from v$resource_limit where resource_name in ('processes','sessions');
```

> 6:55 PM 11 December
>
> processes            490         492               1200       1200 0
>
> sessions               500         504               1920       1920 0

After I observe it that it keep increasing I changed the idle_time in user profile to be 30 minute

> IDLE_TIME          30
>
> CONNECT_TIME               UNLIMITED

after that I observe them for couple of more hours and run same query above and here is the results respectively.

> 8:25 PM 11 December
>
> JDBC Thin Client                oracleUser KILLED   schemename 683
>
> JDBC Thin Client                oracleuser INACTIVE
>   schemeName 241
>
> SQL Developer  SYS         INACTIVE             SYS         4

```
8:25 AM 12 December

processes            995         998               1200       1200 0

sessions               1003       1007             1920       1920 0
```

NOW I see killed session and less inactive session, but they number of session keep increasing it does not drop I was expecting that changing idle_time in profile will kill inactive session and release the session and processes.

my concern is that when the session and processes hit the limit I set, I will getting again the same **minus one error** . and it will kill application also.

"got minus one from a read call"

any help will be highly  appreciated

regards

Comment: You need to configure in the application server connection pool to the database.The application server forgets about open sessions and creates new database sessions.If you can not configure a connection pool, then the solution is only one - to kill the non-active session.

Comment: You can select the desired criterion for the session and kill them.`select  sid, serial#, username, SECONDS_IN_WAIT
from v$session
where type='USER'  and  SECONDS_IN_WAIT>1200;`